# How can I backup the transaction logs when i backup an Azure database?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, database-backups

I currently backup and Azure database with the following script:

```
 param([string]$ConnectionString = 
 “Server=tcp:….database.windows.net,1433;Database=testdatabase;User 
   ID=something@server;Password=pwd;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection 
      Timeout=30;” 
  [string]$DatabaseName = "testdatabase",
  [string]$OutputFile = "c:\backups\testbackup.bacpac",
  [string]$SqlInstallationFolder = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server")
 
   Add-Type -Path "$SqlInstallationFolder\110\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"
   $Services = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $ConnectionString
  if ($Services -eq $null)
  {
     exit
  }
  $Services.ExportBacpac($OutputFile, $DatabaseName)
```

That part works and the file is created.
But how do i know if the transaction logs are being backed up aswell so when i do a restore they are there ?
I want to perform something similar to a transactional log backups along with a full backup.
Is this possible with the above script ?

Comment: Are you talking about an Azure SQL Database? I don't understand why you are doing that. Backups are take every minute and you can restore them with a click. Why doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BACPAC file and method you are using is not fit for your purpose.

A BACPAC is a snapshot of the data, and doesn't contain any information that will allow you to restore back prior to the moment the BACPAC was created. BACPACs are useful for transferring copies to on-prem servers, Devs for bug analysis/development or moving databases between versions of SQL easily but are not a backup solution.

[See here for more information about, and common uses for BACPAC/DACPAC files.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eff3908e-1f9b-48fe-8a99-5df2b01fa85f/several-questions-about-azure-and-bacpacs?forum=ssdsgetstarted)

In the context of an Azure SQL database (either single database or pooled) the concept of transaction logs as you know it has changed. In the modern context the need to restore back to prior moments in time is covered by the PiTR and LTR backup features found in the Azure Portal.

PiTR (or **P**oint in **T**ime **R**estore) gives you the ability to restore a database to ***any millisecond in time*** up to 31 days in the past (depending on configured settings per database). I've used this many times and the hardest part is converting UTC (which the Azure Portal works in) to the local time you need your database restored back to.

LTR (or **L**ong **T**erm **R**etention) backups give you weekly, monthly or yearly options for saving backups. [Here is a good MS Doc article on the subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database) that states:

> When you restore a database from an LTR, the service determines which full, differential, and transaction log backups need to be restored.

We've had well over 100 client databases on Azure SQL for about 3 years now (mix of single databases and elastic pools) and we've never come across a restore request that we couldn't cater to. The 31 days of PiTR really is a killer feature.

***UPDATE***
This is where you go to view what LTR backups are available for a specific database:

Go to the database in question in the Azure Portal, go to *Data Management -> Backups* blade, and click *Manage* next to the database you want to view. You'll see something like this that should reflect the LTR backup configuration you have for that database.

[image]

Ive also since found [this link to an MS Docs article that states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/long-term-retention-overview):

> Note
>
> You can use SQL Agent jobs to schedule copy-only database backups as an alternative to LTR beyond 35 days.

This might be useful in helping you get the configuration you need to fit the requirement.

Comment: This is a solution , but I want to automate the process without user intervention. So if i need to do a restore then I want to do it via a Powershell script . Is it possible by taking a full backup of the database in Azure then   copying it into a storage and if required restore a backup from storage ?    Also how can i view the fullbackups of the database that have been taken and restore the last know full backup , or am i missing something ?

Comment: Your thinking is still inthe frame of traditional on-prem SQL. Azure SQL backup is totally different and requires a shift of thinking. The process is already automated by the scheduling function inside the Azure Portal, and traditional SQL *.BAK backup files just don't exist in Azure SQL.

Comment: that part now clearer.  Can i view the backups in Azure and what type of backup it was, full, incremental etc  ? Even configure Azure to take full backups every 2nd day ?

Comment: Yes, you can view the available LTR backups in the Azure Portal, will update my answer to show you this shortly.  Regarding configuring Azure to take full backups every 2nd day, The timing of individual LTR backups is controlled by Azure and cant be modified beyond what the Portal allows. The PiTR feature in combination with LTR supersedes this absolutely and totally in most cases I believe. 31 days of PiTR plus weekly LTR backups is more than enough for any application I've come across.